# 3D or 2D graphics in c/c++?

Tags: c, bgi

I need to construct a circuit from a structural program and break it and interchange the parts.

I was wondering how do I do that in C++/C?I try drawing graphics using ***graphics.h*** line by line,circle by circle its s time consuming!!! Is there any other way of doing it?

I use turbo C and dev c++.

Comment: Yes. SFML would be one solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to draw every line and circle through your code,there won't be a shortcut for that. Though, I would suggest using other graphics libraries like OpenGL. In other languages certain IDEs have features wherein you don't have to write a code but you can manually design your graphics on a editor window and the code behind is generated on it's own. I'm not sure if there are any such IDEs for c/c++.